# Why does changing app.js to app.tsx break my Next.js project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm trying to set up the Next.js framework with TypeScript, and I'm able to change my `pages/index.js` page to an `pages/index.tsx` page without issue, but when I attempt to change `pages/_app.js` to `pages/_app.tsx`, the project breaks with the error:

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open `/../../pages/_app.js`

Why is this happening? I've installed TypeScript, @types/react, and @types/node

Comment: Probably the module loader is looking for the extension `js` and not for `tsx`.

Answer (score 2):

You may do the following

1. Close the script i.e. `npm run dev`
2. Delete .next folder
3. Run the app again (`npm run dev`). It should work now.

I think it is a problem with caching

Comment: Thanks! Deleting the .next folder actually helped!

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty `tsconfig.json` file in the root of your project.

The then run `run next dev`

Answer (score 0):

1. Stop the script from running ctrl+c (Mac) on terminal.
2. Write this in _app.tsx: `export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps): JSX.Element { return <Component {...pageProps} />  }`
3. Re-run the script npm run dev